# Cancel selection marks when menu is clicked

Tags: javascript, css

I have this menu that opens upon a click, which has 3 animated spans.
usually I used it for touch devices, but now I use it also for desktop sites, and I don't want the selection marks to show when a user clicks the menu button (they doesn't show on touch devices so i didn't notice that so far).
[Here's a link for what I'm doing](http://91.202.168.37/~ibi/)
I don't want this:
[image]

I want that the blue marks will not be visible.
I am sorry if someone asked for a solution before me, I couldn't find it.
Thanks ahead.

Comment: This is outline shows to you. 
Try button:focus{
  outline: none;
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting this in your css, it seems to fix it:

```
.triggerMobileMenu:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```